# Простенький ajax php+mysql чат вопрос нагрузки

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli

Есть онлайн браузерная игра, где на всех страницах есть мини чатик с малой активностью( менее 500 сообщенний в день )
так вот обновление чата происходит каждую секунду через ajax

На стороне сервера в пхп идет запрос к бд на наличие новых сообщений и это как вы понимаете сильно будет грузить базу(?) если игроков например 100+ в онлайне

я его переделал так чтобы при новом сообщении от пользователя последние 30 сообщений писались в json файле например chatMsg.json и ajax уже делает запрос не на пхп файл с запросом в базу, а загружает json файл

```js
$.ajax({
 url: "base/chat/chatMsg.json", 
 cache: false,
}).done(function(json) {
```

правильно ли это? вебсокеты использовать нету возможности

Comment: Это своеобразный кэш. Как снижение нагрузки - сойдет. Единственная проблема, так как обновление может быть частое - это локирование файла. Почитайте про это http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=fs&page=003 . Либо установите готовый пакет по реализации кэша.

Comment: @Pavel ну если активность в чате маленькая сойдет? ведь файл перезаписывается только если написать что то

Answer (score 0):

> Ремарка:
>   текст ниже - не утверждение, а рассуждение.
>   сам с интересом "послушаю" про это.

есть такая штука:

- Http Polling
- [Http Long Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)

и

- [Server-sent events](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)

чуточку статей:

- [Polling vs SSE vs WebSocket— How to choose the right one](https://codeburst.io/polling-vs-sse-vs-websocket-how-to-choose-the-right-one-1859e4e13bd9)
- [Создание приложений реального времени с помощью Server-Sent Events](https://habr.com/ru/post/120429/)
- [Простая реализация long polling механизма на PHP](https://habr.com/ru/post/128535/)
  там в комментах, упоминают:

  - [dklab_realplexor](http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realplexor/)
- [How To Do AJAX Long Polling With PHP MySQL](https://code-boxx.com/ajax-long-polling-php-mysql)

  > In short, long polling is kind of a “necessary evil”… It is still bad, but it is much better than getting hammered.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно, вполне годный вариант. Если нагрузка вырастет очень сильно и опять же не будет возможности использовать websocket, то отдавать такие json можно будет через весьма простое приложение на golang - тогда потребление памяти будет минимальным. Или правильно настроенный nginx вполне сможет отдавать по 90k в секунду таких файлов, при конфигурации linux сервера 4Gb RAM, 20GB HDD. Я подобное проверял на online radio player. А если данных не сильно много, то можно использовать redis ) тогда совсем все будет быстро с минимальными задержками и минимальными нагрузками на файловую систему, так как данные будут отдаваться сразу из оперативной памяти.